# Array as key for a Hash. How to access values, how to format properly?

Tags: ruby

```
t = {
 "Bachelor" => [1,2,3],
 "Master" => [4,5,6]
}

r = t.invert
=> {[1, 2, 3]=>"Bachelor", [4, 5, 6]=>"Master"}

r[1]
=> nil
```

My question is, how do I access the value for key 1,2 etc in the example mentioned?

How to convert this to: `{"1"=> "Bachelor","2"=> "Bachelor"..}` etc?

Comment: Is it possible: `t = { "Bachelor" => [1,2,3], "Master" => [1,5,6] }`?

Answer (score 1):

```
res = t.each_with_object({}) do |(key, vals), res|
  vals.each do |val|
    res[val] = key
  end
end
```

```
res[1]
=> "Bachelor"
res
=> {1=>"Bachelor", 2=>"Bachelor", 3=>"Bachelor", 4=>"Master", 5=>"Master", 6=>"Master"}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could give your hash a default procedure which runs whenever the key can't be found:

```
t = {
 "Bachelor" => [1,2,3],
 "Master" => [4,5,6]
}

r = t.invert

r.default_proc = proc do |hash, key|
  hash.find{|k,v| k.include?(key) }.last
end

#demo:
puts r[5] # => Master
```

Another useful mechanism which does not use a hash is a `case when` construct:

```
num=5
title = case num
  when 1..3 then "Bachelor"
  when 4..6 then "Master"
end
```

Comment: Consider addressing `{"Bachelor" => [1,2,3], "Master" => [4,2,6]}` versus `{"Master" => [4,2,6], "Bachelor" => [1,2,3]}`.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new hash by iterating through the array keys of `t.invert`:

```rb
h = t.invert.map do |k,v|
  k.map {|kk| {kk => v} } }.flatten.inject(:merge)
=> {1=>"Bachelor", 2=>"Bachelor", 3=>"Bachelor", 4=>"Master", 5=>"Master", 6=>"Master"}

h[1]
=> "Bachelor"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
res = {} 
t.each { |key, values| values.inject(res) { |h, i| h[i] = key; h }}

res[1] 
=> "Bachelor"
res 
=> {1=>"Bachelor", 2=>"Bachelor", 3=>"Bachelor", 4=>"Master", 5=>"Master", 6=>"Master"}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26205195)